# Wordpress Create a "One time" Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is there a way to set up a custom post type in Wordpress so that it can only create ONE initial post and from there only that one can be edited? In one of my custom posts I created it doesn't matter if more are added and only one is needed because it's mainly using the featured image option that I can just edit that as needed, so I figured I'd just not program in the option to add more if that's possible.

Comment: I don't get this sentence: *"I figured I'd just not program in the option to add more if that's possible."*

Comment: You know in the registration for the labels array, where you put in add new.